# How to login in Magento store website from outside of Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have installed magento on my local system.

Below is my main website link.

> http://10.7.0.120/magento/

then I have created new website from backend. below is the link:

> http://10.7.0.120/magento/samplewebsite

Now below is the code to login in magento site from outside of magento which works perfect on main site (`http://10.7.0.120/magento/`)

http://10.7.0.120/test.php

```
<?php
    header('Location: http://10.7.0.120/magento/MyLogin.php/?Email='.$email.'&Password='.$password);
?>
```

http://10.7.0.120/magento/MyLogin.php/

```
umask(0);
ob_start();
session_start();
Mage::app();
session_write_close(); // Write the data, end session
unset($_SESSION); // unset the session, magento uses isset($_SESSION) to check if it
session_name("frontend");// change the session name to frontend

$session = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' );
$session->login( $_GET['Email'], $_GET['Password'] );
$session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($session->getCustomer());

$storeUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);

if ($session->isLoggedIn()) 
{
    $custSessionId = Mage::getModel("core/session")->getEncryptedSessionId();

    header('Location: http://10.7.0.120/magento/?SID='.$custSessionId);
    return;
}
```

Above code works perfect on `http://10.7.0.120/magento/`

Now I want to Login in store website means different website ID and different store ID. So I change some code in above code as below:

```
umask(0);
ob_start();
session_start();
Mage::app();
session_write_close(); // Write the data, end session
unset($_SESSION); // unset the session, magento uses isset($_SESSION) to check if it
session_name("frontend");// change the session name to frontend

$session = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' , array('name' => 'frontend'));
$session->login( $_GET['Email'], $_GET['Password'] );
$session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($session->getCustomer());

$storeUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);

if ($session->isLoggedIn()) 
{
    $custSessionId = Mage::getModel("core/session")->getEncryptedSessionId();

    header('Location: http://10.7.0.120/magento/samplewebsite?SID='.$custSessionId);
    return;
}
```

I have changed only url but its not working.

Comment: Where do you tell Magento the `website id` and `store id` on the second example?!

Comment: I have not mentioned it but the user email and password is a customer of only that website and store id.

Comment: I'm not completly sure, but isn't it needed to tell wich store/type you want to log into when starting the app? Like `Mage::app('samplewebsite', 'website');`. It's not tested, just an idea ...

Comment: No.. I have tried it.. it is also not working..
By using `$session->login( $_GET['Email'], $_GET['Password'] );` it gives me error so i have tried directly with user id using `$session->loginById(5);` It is also not working.

Comment: Do you get errors in general, or only with my change? If first, please add all errors to the question.

Comment: I got Below Error But user is available in different store id `Invalid login or password.' in /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php:58`

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid login or password.' in /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php:580 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php(190): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Invalid login o...', 2) #1 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php(214): Mage_Customer_Model_Customer->authenticate('prashant@seffco...', '123456') #2 /var/www/html/magento/holyspiritschool/MyLogin.php(107): Mage_Customer_Model_Session->login('prashant@seffco...', '123456') #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/htm...`